# Prolog program for family hierarchy

Tags: prolog

I am trying to find the rules based on the facts and write some sample queries. But I can't understand other query logic.

```
% parent(X,Y) means that person X is a parent (father or mother) of person Y

parent(alex,julia).
parent(alex,rosa).
parent(lina,julia).
parent(lina,rosa).
parent(romeo,peter).
parent(julia,peter).
parent(rosa,silvia).
parent(oscar,ida).
parent(eva,ida).
parent(eva,bruno).
parent(peter,bruno).
parent(peter,georg).
parent(peter,irma).
parent(ruth,georg).
parent(ruth,irma).
parent(silvia,otto).
parent(silvia,pascal).
parent(irma,olga).
parent(irma,jean).
parent(otto,olga).
parent(otto,jean).
parent(jean,tina).
parent(marie,tina).

% male(X) means that X is a male person

male(alex).
male(romeo).
male(oscar).
male(peter).
male(bruno).
male(georg).
male(otto).
male(pascal).
male(jean).

% husband(X,Y) means that person X is the husband of person Y

husband(alex,lina).
husband(romeo,julia).
husband(oscar,eva).
husband(peter,ruth).
husband(otto,irma).
husband(jean,marie).


% female
 female(X) :- \+ male(X).

% father
father(X,Y) :- parent(X,Y),male(X).

% mother
mother(X,Y) :- parent(X,Y),female(X).

% son
son(X,Y) :- male(X),parent(Y,X).

% daughter
daughter(X,Y) :- female(X),parent(Y,X).

% sibling


% brother


% sister


% wife


% grandchild


% grandparent


% grandfather


% grandmother


% uncle



% halfbrother


% halfsister


% stepbrother


% stepsister


% ancestor


% descendant



% father-in-law


% mother-in-law




% familycomn
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.  Please post some code that maybe we can help you with.  We cannot understand things for you.

Comment: @EricHauenstein I don't think Prolog was meant to be understood by mere mortals.  Artificial intelligence, if you know what I mean, wink wink nudge nudge.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Well, that's a relief.  I'm glad some robot or other is available to answer.

Comment: @lurker Why the edit?  Prolog (well, Yap in any case) can handle multiple facts on one line.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille the OP had them on separate lines originally but didn't use the proper SO mark-up for formatting code. I actually didn't touch the formatting at all. I just made the OP's original formatting "visible" using the correct markup (indenting all of the lines by four spaces). See the actual edit contents.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I think Prolog is easy to understand and fairly simple in the sense that it doesn't have a large number of syntactical programming concepts one must learn (as in a language such as C++). What makes it difficult for people is when they try to think of Prolog as if it were just like other languages but with different and limited syntax. That makes it difficult, tedious, and annoying. I recommend to Prolog nubes to forget everything they know about programming and learn how Prolog actually works. Then it's easy. The challenge comes with creating logically pure solutions. :)

Comment: I can't forget everything I know about programming, or I would be out of a job.

Answer (score 1):

```
% female female(X) :- + male(X).
```

X is a female if X is not a male (Prolog predates gender fluidity).

```
% father father(X,Y) :- parent(X,Y),male(X).
```

X is the father of Y if X is a parent of Y and X is male

% Sibling

```
sibling(X,Y) :- dif(X,Y),parent(Z,X),parent(Z,Y).
```

Y and X are siblings if they have a parent in common, but are not one and the same person (cfr. @lurker)

Comment: Your `sibling(X, Y)` definition needs `dif(X, Y)` as well so that you don't get that `X` is a sibling of `X`.

Comment: Isn't  he or she?

Comment: No. One is not their own sibling. Not by the normal definition of "sibling".

Comment: That's  why I originally had "probably" ;-)   Haven't touched Prolog in thirty years.

Answer (score 0):

% sibling
sibling(X,Y) :- father(P,X), father(P,Y), mother(Q,X), mother(Q,Y).

% brother
brother(X,Y) :- sibling(X,Y), male(X).

% sister
sister(X,Y) :- sibling(X, Y), female(X).

% wife
wife(X,Y) :- husband(Y,X).

% grandchild
grandchild(X,Y) :- grandparent(Y,X).

% grandparent
grandparent(X,Y) :- parent(Z,Y), parent(X,Z).

% grandfather
grandfather(X,Y) :- grandparent(X,Y), male(X).

% grandmother
grandmother(X,Y) :- grandparent(X,Y), female(X).

% uncle
uncle(X,Y) :- parent(Z,Y), brother(X,Z).

% halfbrother
halfbrother(X,Y) :- halfsibling(X,Y), male(X).

% halfsister
halfsister(X,Y) :- halfsibling(X,Y), female(X).

% stepbrother
stepbrother(X,Y) :- stepsibling(X,Y) , male(X).

% stepsister
stepsister(X,Y) :- stepsibling(X,Y) , female(X).

% ancestor
ancestor(X, Y) :- parent(X,Y); parent(X,Z), ancestor(Z,Y).

% descendant
descendant(X, Y) :- ancestor(Y,X).